# Http server output error

Tags: java, fileoutputstream, httpserver

I have wrote a code for a basic http server. When a client connects to the server he receives a file as a response.
When send only one file out it works fine, however when oi tried to introduce a loop in order to send the same file many times, i receive this error: 
`sun.net.httpserver.StreamClosedException`.

Here is me code:

```
public class SimpleServer {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      HttpServer server = HttpServer.create(new InetSocketAddress(8080), 0);
      server.createContext("/getFile", new FileHendler());
      server.setExecutor(null);
      server.start();
  }

  static class FileHendler implements HttpHandler {
      public void handle(HttpExchange t){
      Headers h = t.getResponseHeaders();
      h.add("Content-Type", "file");

      // a file
      LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.now();
      double t = (ldt.getHour()-3)*3600 + ldt.getMinute()*60 + ldt.getSecond();
      File folder = new File ("D:\\outFiles");
      File[] CorFiles = folder.listFiles();
      double tdif = 100000;
      int fileIndx = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < CorFiles.length; i++){
          String[] tmp = CorFiles[i].getName().toString().split("_");
          String Zc = tmp[2].substring(0, tmp[2].length()-4);
          if (Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(Zc) - t) < tdif) {
              fileIndx = i;
              tdif = Math.abs(Double.parseDouble(Zc) - t);
          }
      }
      byte[] bytes  = new byte [(int)CorFiles[fileIndx].length()];

      try {
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(CorFiles[fileIndx]);
        fis.read(bytes);
        // ready to send the response.
        t.sendResponseHeaders(200, CorFiles[fileIndx].length());
        OutputStream os = t.getResponseBody();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            os.write(bytes);
        }
        os.close();    
      } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {System.out.println(ex);} 
        catch (IOException ex) {System.out.println(ex);}  
  }}}
```

what am i doing wrong and how can i fix it?
This `for` loop is only for the example, eventually i would like to do the same but using a different loop and sending a different file every some specified time interval.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you are sending the file, and it works first off. Then you want to send it again at some later point ? What request from the client kicks off the second send? If you just send it without a client requesting it, then the stream will be closed, and the connection gone.

Comment: @jr593 I dont know what kind of request that is. it should probably be the GET request. I am new to the http servers, so i am kind of learning it on the fly. Any suggestions of how should i modify my code in order to work properly? thank you